# Animating toolbar with textfield up above the keyboard when the the textfield is edited

Tags: xcode

Okay I'm looking for some assistance I have researched and read posts that pertain to what I am trying to do, but none of the examples include a toolbar with a URL textfield. I am not looking to make any money off of this browser. I want it for personal use, furthermore I am not trying to insult nor take what you guys do as a profession as a joke. So if I come across that way I sincerely apologize. My toolbar is located at the bottom of the screen and I have a URL textfield. When I use the textfield to enter a website address the keyboard covers the toolbar and I cannot see what I am typing. So if you can offer some assistance that would be greatly appreciated.

I'm getting an error on the CGRect frame =self.scrollView can someone please assist me? Thanks!
I hope my code is not far off the websites load perfectly fine. I just want to move the toolbar up when the textfield is edited and drop back down after go is press....I have tried to include the toolbar inside the scrollview but I do not know what to do after.

Best regards! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CGRect frame = self.scrollView;
```

this line must be:

```
CGRect frame = self.scrollView.frame;
```